# Eval like function by my own in Javascript

Tags: javascript, eval, clone

I am trying to create eval() like function (to calculate expression from string) in Javascript.
I am getting bugs in consecutive '-' operations.
Other than '-' everything is working fine.
Can anyone help me for making '-' to work
for live preview codepen link- https://codepen.io/raj1998211/pen/yvVXLd

```
function mat(str){
  // var sum = 0;
  ns = str;
  while(ns.indexOf('/') > 0){
    var regex = /(\d+|(\d+\.\d+))(\/)((\d+\.\d+)|\d+)/g;
     var ns = ns.replace(regex, function(a){
      arr = a.split("/");    
      ans = Number(arr[0]) / Number(arr[1]);
      return ans;
    });
    // console.log(ns);
  }
  while(ns.indexOf('*') > 0){
    var regex = /(\d+|(\d+\.\d+))(\*)((\d+\.\d+)|\d+)/g;
    var ns = ns.replace(regex, function(a){
      arr = a.split("*");    
      ans = Number(arr[0]) * Number(arr[1]);
      return ans;
    });
    // str = ns;
    // console.log(ns);
  }

  while(ns.indexOf('-') > 0){
    var regex = /(\-\d+|\d+|(\d+\.\d+))(\-)((\d+\.\d+)|\d+)/g;
    var ns = ns.replace(regex, function(a){
      arr = a.split("-");    
      ans = Number(arr[0]) - Number(arr[1]);
      return Math.abs(ans);
      // return ans;
    });
    // console.log(ns);
  }
//   if(ns.indexOf('-') === 0){

//   }

  if(ns.indexOf('+') > 0){
    arr = ns.split("+");
    sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      sum += Number(arr[i]);
    }
    ns = sum;
  }
  // return "sum";
  return ns;
}

console.log(mat("4-5-1")); //infinite loop if '-' comes on first char of str
```

Comment: So, *what* bugs are you getting, with which example inputs?

Comment: Could you describe what that mixture of regex and indexOf should do?

Comment: `while(ns.indexOf('-') > 0)` is probably not a good looping condition if you want to deal with temporary results such as `-1 + -4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider whether this works as intended, since any negative number will break your code. (example: mat("1+-1")). Consider if regular expressions has the expressive power needed to parse your expressions, as they are pretty limited. (example you can't check for balanced parenthesis with regular expressions alone)

You probably want to look into parsing, there are a lot of tutorials online describing this.

You might also want to look up the limitations of regular languages (which is what regular expressions can express / "parse")

The next step up is probably to look into what is called "context free grammars", which has more expressive power.

For full on parsing, some useful keywords are "Tokenizing" and "Abstract syntax trees". Hope some of this can help you research what you need.

Comment: OP is using a term rewriting approach. Regexes can work fine in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 4-5 yields -1, so after the first replacement you get

`-1-1`, leading to an infinte loop, or, with your `abs()` hack

`1-1`, which leads to a wrong result.

One option would be to remove the `abs()` hack and to use `ns.indexOf('-', 1)`, but this might cause problems with negative numbers down the line -- and your number regex doesn't seem to deal with negative numbers either... So you'd need to address this, too.

One option to address this might be:

- Add a preprocessing step replacing all '-' surrounded by digits with some other character, e.g. '%'
- All remaining '-' are unary. Extend your regular expressions to include a unary minus accordingly
- Change the binary minus processing code to use '%' instead.

Alternatively, you could use a recursive approach like this instead of your term rewriting approach:

```
function mat(str) {
  var operators = "/*-+"; 
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var op = operators.charAt(i);
    var pos = str.indexOf(op);
    if (pos > 0 && operators.indexOf(str.charAt(pos - 1)) == -1) {
      var left = mat(str.substr(0, pos));
      var right = mat(str.substr(pos + 1));
      switch (op) {
        case "/": return left / right;
        case "*": return left * right;
        case "-": return left - right;
        case "+": return left + right; 
      }
    }
  }
  return Number(str);
}
```